# Cloning an android project from github from Mac pc to Windows pc gives error R cannot be resolved

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I have two laptops one is Windows and one is Mac OS. I created a android project in Mac OS with Android Studio and shared the project on github.

When I try to clone that project with the url in my Windows laptop Android Studio it always show `"symbol R cannot be resolved"`. But if I try to clone project in Mac OS it is working fine. What could be the issue?

Does the OS platform change matters?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happened because some Android Studio configuration in Mac OS are getting tracked in your git. The configuration is in `.idea` directories.

To fix the problem, remove the project `.iml` and let the Android Studio recreated it.

To permanently fix the problem, add `.idea` and `.iml` to your `.gitignore` list. Something like this:

```
# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea
```

If you need keep some Android Studio configuration for your project, add the unnecessary ones to your `.gitignore`:

```
# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
# etc
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the project .iml file and rebuild your project